Why has my HP OfficeJet Pro 8620 printer disappeared in Kubuntu?
I have been running an HP OfficeJet Pro 8620 for years in Kubuntu (now 24.04). Suddenly, something is wrong with the CUPS package: I can only find driverless entries!
Following CUPS package reinstall instructions do not solve the problem. How to actually reinstall the CUPS package, including the /var/lib/cups/filter directory?

Can you share with us the steps you followed to reinstall CUPS, the steps that failed? Do you know the printer is working correctly? Does it communicate with other computers OK?

After trying some quick fixes (remove cups, install cups kind of thing) I used a combination command of sudo apt purge cups && (reinstall cups) && (something else). This did not reinstall the directory I referenced; therefore, I got an error message in the printer display window that I was missing a file in that directory. Obviously, cups was not removed nor reinstalled. Reinstall Kubuntu 24.04?  : (

The printer is fine - I installed Kubuntu 24.04 on an old rotating drive, aligned the printer, it printed correctly. My printer is on a local network, and after is reset my Cox router and downloaded a ton of software, everything is working just fine.

So this turned out to be a network issue?
